# Vaadin DateField textfield does not update time value

Tags: datetime, vaadin, datefield

Has anyone had any problems with the updating of the time value when using Vaadin DateField (or PopupDateField)? Whenever a new time is selected from the time drop downs located at the bottom of the popup calendar, the date textfield does not update with the new time selected. Only the day value updates properly when a different day is selected from the calendar. I have registered a Property.ValueChangeListener with my DateField, and through debug I've found that the valueChange() method is only entered when a different day is selected from the popup calendar (and hence updates value in textfield), and not when a different time is selected from the time drop downs. Is this a bug with Vaadin DateField? Or is there a workaround?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
gc

Answer (score 1):

See http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/216876 for answer.